# dragging problem in markers in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am taking marker details from a database.
The code is

```
app.entries[id].data = {'id': id, 'map': entry[1].innerHTML,'type_id':

entry[2].innerHTML,'name': entry[3].innerHTML,'descript':  entry[4].innerHTML, 'parish':

entry[5].innerHTML,'zip': entry[6].innerHTML, 'url': entry[7].innerHTML, 'lng':

entry[8].innerHTML,'lat':entry[9].innerHTML,'tags':entry[10].innerHTML,'img': 

entry[11].innerHTML,'imgs':entry[12].innerHTML};

app.entries[id].data.imgHTML = (app.entries[id].data.img == "") ? "" : 

fill_template(app.entries[id].data,app.infoWindowImageHTML);

var str = fill_template(app.entries[id].data,app.searchRowHTML);

html.push(str);

if (app.entries[id].data.lat != 0 || app.entries[id].data.lng != 0) {

   var point = new GLatLng(app.entries[id].data.lat,app.entries[id].data.lng);

   var m = new GMarker(point,{draggable: true});

   GEvent.addListener(m, "dragstart", function() {

          // map.closeInfoWindow();

      var latlngold = m.getLatLng();

  });

   GEvent.addListener(m, "dragend", function() {
```

var m = new GMarker(point,{draggable: true});

```
 m.entry_id = id;
 var p=m.entry_id;

    var latlngnew = m.getLatLng();

     alert(latlngnew);

     //m.setLatLng(new GLatLng(latlng));

     editentry1(latlngnew,p);

   });
 }
```

The `dragend` and `dragstart` function always takes the last marker's details not the details of dragging marker..

function editentry1(latlngnew,p){

```
     var newlat=latlngnew.lat();

 var newlng=latlngnew.lng();

     var d = new Date();

var dv = d.valueOf();

var url = "<?php echo $g['appPath']; ?>admin/editPoint.php?d="+dv+"&
```

newlat="+newlat+"newlng="+newlng+"&p="+p;

```
 var s = $('mapStatus');
```

s.innerHTML = "EDiting Point...";

s.show();

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {

  method: 'get',

  onSuccess: editEntryReturn,

  onFailure: requestFailed
```

});

}

editPoint.php

require("createThumb.php");

$newlng = $_GET['newlng'];

```
$newlat = $_GET['newlat'];

$p=$_GET['p'];
```

$q = "UPDATE entry SET lat = '$newlat', lng = '$newlng' WHERE id='$p';";

```
  $r = updateBatch($q);
```

}
?>
but the position of the marker doesn't changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your marker creation code in a function. This will create a [closure](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml) in which the drag callbacks can find the appropriate marker object:

```
function createMarker (point)
{
    var m = new GMarker(point,{draggable: true});

    GEvent.addListener(m, "dragstart", function() {
        var latlngold = m.getLatLng();
    });

    GEvent.addListener(m, "dragend", function() {
        var latlngnew = m.getLatLng();
        editentry1(latlngold,latlngnew);
    });

    return m;
}
```

Call this from inside your if statement after getting the point:

```
if (app.entries[id].data.lat != 0 || app.entries[id].data.lng != 0) 
{
    var point = new GLatLng(app.entries[id].data.lat,app.entries[id].data.lng);
    map.addOverlay(createMarker (point));
}
```

Comment: @Ashitha You had commented out the addOverlay code. I have updated my answer with that code back in :)

Comment: Now map appeares and can drag it..but when page refreshes marker remains in the old position